# How to change the image of a MenuSpriteItem Cocos2d-x C++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I've got a button that I need to be a toggle button for the sound of a game. I'm using the MenuSpriteItem class.

```
auto menuSoundOn = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("soundOn.png");
auto menuSoundOff = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("soundOff.png");
auto menuSoundBtn = MenuItemSprite::create(menuSoundOn, menuSoundOff, CC_CALLBACK_1(LevelsLayer::shutSound, this));
menuSoundBtn->setTag(0);

_mainMenu = Menu::create(menuSoundBtn, nullptr);
this->addChild(_mainMenu);

//Then in my shutSound method
auto menuSoundBtn = _mainMenu->getChildByTag(0);
if (_ifSound){
    _ifSound = false;
    //Do some stuff to shut the sound
    menuSoundBtn->setSelectedImage("noSound.png");

}
else{

    _ifSound = true;
    //Do some stuff to bring the sound back
    menuSoundBtn->setSelectedImage("sound.png");

}
```

The problem is that getting the Btn from his parent with getChildByTag(0) method I receive a Node according with the documentation, but setSelectedImage is not part of the Node class and there is an error telling me so, so what is the right way to access MenuSpriteItems from their Parents and then manipulate them as in this case by changing the Normal Image?

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer and It's really powerful and simple.

```
auto menuSoundBtn = dynamic_cast<MenuItemSprite*>(_mainMenu->getChildByTag(0));
```

This is the explanation from the guy:

This code will get the child with tag 0 and turn it into a MenuItemSprite* object if it is a MenuItemSprite* object, or it returns null if the object was not a MenuItemSprite*.

Hope it helps someone. Greetings.